# Aiogram не правильно обрабатывает сообщение от пользователя

Tags: python, aiogram

Начал изучать Aiogram, хочу сделать очень простого бота, который генерил бы 2 числа a,b от -100 до 100 и присылал бы a*b, от пользователя ожидал бы правильный ответ.

```
a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['math_task'])
async def math_task(message:types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                            text='Начинаем')

    await message.answer(text=('Перемножить',a,b))

@dp.message_handler()
async def math_task(message:types.Message):
    c = a * b
    if message.text==c:
        await message.answer("YES")
    else:
        await message.answer('NO')
```

бот реагирует на любой ответ пользователя NO.
пробовал message.text==c заменить message.text in c.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы сравниваете два разных типа переменных “1“ == 1, которые не когда не будут равны преобразуйте к одному типу переменных "1" == str(1)

Comment: Спасибо, а как теперь реализовать все это в цикле while, чтобы после ответа выдавал другие 2 числа, раз 5 например. как просто в python я знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надеюсь ответ устроит ( в данном случае это бесконечный цикл)

```
a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['math_task'])
async def math_task(message:types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,text='Начинаем')

    await message.answer(text=f'Перемножить {a}, {b}')

@dp.message_handler()
async def math_task(message:types.Message):
    global a,b
    c = a * b
    if str(message.text)==str(c):
        await message.answer("Правильно")
        a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        await message.answer(text=f'Перемножить {a}, {b}')
        math_task
    else:
        await message.answer('Неправильно, пробуй еще.')

executor.start_polling(dp)
```

но можно запихнуть в цикл for или while (например)

```
for a in range(5): #или while something:
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def math_task(message: types.Message):
        global a, b
        c = a * b
        if str(message.text) == str(c):
            await message.answer("Правильно")
            a = random.randrange(-100, 100)
            b = random.randrange(-100, 100)
            await message.answer(text=f'Перемножить {a}, {b}')
        else:
            await message.answer('Неправильно, пробуй еще.')
```

Comment: Все нашел, Спасибо.

Comment: Я так понял синтаксис библиотеки не позволяет async def в цикле исполнять?

Comment: @Mr.Kim в данном случае позволяет.

Comment: я имел ввиду while

Comment: @Mr.Kim можно, отредактировал ответ

Comment: Я немного усложнил бота, вылезли новые проблемы, если не сложно, посмотрите  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477966/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%91%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8